# Making a singing greeting card

Tags: integrated-circuit, ldr

I have very limited knowledge of electronics (the little that I learnt in high school physics) and I'd like to make a customized singing birthday card for my sister.

The card could be triggered with a light dependent resistor. I was wondering if this would be a good choice to get some hands on with electronics
http://www.aplusinc.com.tw/proimages/Recording%20Ic/aPR2060/aPR2060_K2.1_Datasheet_20140324.pdf

Or I should just buy this http://aplusindia.net/aplusindiauser/ProductDetailAction.apu?cat_id=79&prodno=Light%20Sensitive%20Musical%20Greeting%20Card%20M

Comment: This is a shopping question. Vote to close.

Comment: @coldbreeze, this isn't the best site to learn electronics. You might find hackaday or sparkfun to be better forums for your learning. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not trying for a birthday very soon, and you're willing to try some simpler projects first, your DIY version is possible, with the caveat that it won't be nearly as pretty as a commercial version. You'll need to play around with all sorts of circuits to get a feel for how electronics work, and the final goal needs to be fairly well in the future, unless you can get someone who does know what he's doing to take you under her wing.

You'd probably have a hard time finding a distributor for the IC, and the parent company probably isn't interested in selling you one or two.

And also be aware that the IC wont' drive just any speaker, either. It will only drive a high-impedance unit, although the data sheet does give a sample circuit to use a transistor to boost output abilities. I just mention this as one example of the sort of thing you'd need to learn about, and probably the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

I've used these ISD chips before: -

[image]

You can even buy them already assembled: -

[image]

This one uses the ISD1820 and [here's](http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=Voice_Record_Module_-_ISD1820) another link to the module. The 2560 in the first diagram can record 60 seconds at 8 kHz sampling whilst the 1860 is only good for 20 seconds. [Ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=isd+voice+module&LH_ItemCondition=1000&clk_rvr_id=1059201832759&adpos=1o1&treatment_id=7&crlp=110802219491_817&MT_ID=10&device=c&rlsatarget=kwd-119345215949&keyword=isd+voice+module&geo_id=32251&poi=&crdt=0&ul_noapp=true) seem to stock a gazillion different kits at what seem remarkably low prices.